# XML validate a part of the XML of type anytype with external xsd

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I have an XML with a body tag of type anyType. The contents of this body tag I wish to validate with a XSD. But the content of this tag is a part of the XML that conforms to the XSD. SO its only one of the element of the XSD. If I validate it against the entire XSD it fails naturally. Is there a way by which I can validate the XML with a element of the XSD and not the entire XSD?

Comment: You would need to post the significant parts of the XSD; namely the entire hierarchy from the element that is of anyType (referenced or locally defined) to a top schema component (element, complex type type or group). You should also illustrate what do you mean by "importing the external XSD in parent XSD", and what is it you put in the "external XSD" that you thought should affect the validation. Bits of XML might also be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to validate the XML with a framework or don't you mind writing your own validator?